# feature extraction using vl_feat toolbox

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, sift, vlfeat

```
imshow(imread(a));
img = single(imread(a));
[f,d] = vl_phow(img);
perm = randperm(size(f,2)) ;
s = perm(1:50)
h1= vl_plotframe(f(:,s));
h2= vl_plotframe(f(:,s));
set(h1,'color','k','linewidth',3) ;
set(h2,'color','y','linewidth',2) ;
h3 = vl_plotsiftdescriptor(f(:,s),d(:,s)) ;
set(h3,'color','g') ;
```

But when I try to plot them using `vl_plotsiftdescriptors`, it gives an error.

> whos 
>   d   128x3692 uint8
>   f   4x3692   double

The error is:

> The number of rows of D does not match the geometry of the descriptor

Could someone please help me with this? 
Am I doing it the right way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
h3 = vl_plotsiftdescriptor(f(:,s),d(:,s)) ;
```

with `f(:,s)` and `d(:,s)`, you are loading the `s`-th *row* of `f` and `s`, while the [VLFeat documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_sift.html) states, that

> Each column of `D` is the descriptor of the corresponding frame in `F`.

So to extract the descriptors at index `s`, you'll instead have to call

```
h3 = vl_plotsiftdescriptor(f(s,:),d(s,:)) ;
```

--

Additional comment: By using the second parameter (`k`) of [`randperm`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html), you can replace

```
perm = randperm(size(f,2)) ;
s = perm(1:50);
```

by

```
s = randperm(size(f,2), 50);
```

which should be faster, as you only generate 50 random numbers, instead of generating `size(f,2)` numbers and discarding most of them.